# How to remove a locale (i.e. to drop it from `$LANGUAGE` variable)?

Tags: administration, language-support, locale

For some reason I have an extra unneeded language installed on my system (more precisely, `$LANGUAGE` variable is `ru:en_CA:en` where supposed to be `ru:en`, and also apt tries to load addresses like `http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_CA`).

How can I remove the unneeded `en_CA` language?

- `language-selector` doesn't have an option to remove a language
- `localepurge` doesn't help

---

Don't think I'm fake Dmitry Shachnev, I just had to drop my previous account…

Comment: Aside, why did you have to remove your previous account? You can send an email to the team for account recovery. See the bottom of this page for the contact link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather recommend using the standard GUI apps to do this. With Language Selector you can drag en_CA out of the list of languages (i.e. below the 'English' entry), and that should remove it from your LANGUAGE variable without having to manually edit system files.

You'll then need to log out and log back into your session for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks, David! It's quite unobvious that it can be dragged down…

Comment: It is indeed. Next cycle we might go with the upstream language widget and add language installation capabilities to it.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudoedit /etc/default/locale
```

Edit the `LANGUAGE` variable to remove `en_CA`. Then reboot.

After that you can run `localepurge` to remove old locale files.

Comment: Thanks, and other reader: You have to install it with `sudo apt-get install localepurge`